# How to compare system month and sales months?

Tags: oracle

I want to compare sales months with the system month. if equal get 1 output as new column(last_month) else 0. I tried below oracle query but I am getting a Null value.

```
SELECT   a.agent_id,a.agent_name,a.ivr_registered_district,s.agent_type,s.district,s.province,a.parent_level1_id,a.parent_level1,a.sales_channel,TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.connection_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTHYEAR,
       
        CASE
         WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.connection_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 1))
         THEN 1 
         END as last_month
       
       
     
FROM   EDW_TGT.FACT_LTE_SALES_CHANNELS a
JOIN SFA.sfa_agent_dtl s
ON a.agent_id = s.agent_id
where a.pre_post = 'LTE-PREPAID' and a.sales_channel in ('BUSINESS PARTNER', 'INSTITUSIONAL', 'REGIONAL TRADE PARTNERS', 'DISTRIBUTOR')
and  a.connection_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: What is the data type of connection_date?  It _should_ be DATE, but all proposed solutions will depend on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to truncate date as oracle provides you functionality to extract (day,month,year) from to_date function.

Your query should be like below.

```
SELECT   a.agent_id,a.agent_name,a.ivr_registered_district,s.agent_type,s.district,s.province,a.parent_level1_id,a.parent_level1,a.sales_channel,TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.connection_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTHYEAR,
       
         CASE
         WHEN to_char(to_date(a.connection_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') = to_char(to_date(sysdate-1, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month')
         THEN 1
         Else 0
         END as last_month      
     
  FROM   EDW_TGT.FACT_LTE_SALES_CHANNELS a
  JOIN SFA.sfa_agent_dtl s
  ON a.agent_id = s.agent_id
  where a.pre_post = 'LTE-PREPAID' and a.sales_channel in ('BUSINESS PARTNER',    'INSTITUSIONAL', 'REGIONAL TRADE PARTNERS', 'DISTRIBUTOR')
  and  a.connection_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: May I suggest that instead of doing the unnecessary date conversions in the CASE statement, you use the `extract` function instead. `a.connection_date` and `sysdate` are already dates, no need to call to_date() then to_char(). Simply call `WHEN extract(month from a.connection_date) = extract(month FROM sysdate-1)` to save the overhead (albeit tiny) of converting dates to dates and back to strings.

Comment: @SamM - why are you suggesting applying to_date to the date column a.connection_date?  We need to get clarification from the OP on the data type of connection_date.  It really should be a DATE, and if so, applying to_date would be improper and possibly error prone, depending on the setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: @EdStevens I'm not suggesting that to_date() be applied; in fact I am suggesting the opposite. As you said in your comment, applying to_date may introduce errors. My suggestion is to use the extract() function on the date fields instead of doing intermediate datatype conversions.